# XOR on streams, reading and writing

Tags: .net, serialization, encryption, stream

My recent turn-on is using BinaryFormatter instead of some database product.  I have an idea to write simple 64bit number into hardware dongle, and encrypt my files with it - via simple XOR operation.  Just so it can't be readable at some other end.  Do I derive from Stream, or what?

I know I can simply put that number into the file and check against it on reading, but...  I'll feel better if it's XORed all the way.

Comment: I would like to comment that I don't plan to do hacker-proof version here.  If I don't obfuscate, it's relatively simple to extract key from the dongle anyway, so any real encryption should be INSIDE the dongle and not done in the code.  Since I don't have such device, but a simple HASP, I'll go with XOR here (maybe few extra tricks like incrementing 'key' value with some prime number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to comment on XOR encryption, that's too silly.  Lets focus on practical guidance to implement your custom stream.  You should derive it from Stream so it has a familiar interface to the user.  Right-click "Stream", Implement Abstract Class.  You can leave most of the NotImplementedException throws in place, streams are commonly crippled like this.  Add a private FileStream member, it will do the hard work.  Then add:

- A contructor that takes a string argument, the path to the file.  Construct the FileStream with it.
- Implement CanWrite, return true.
- Implement the Write() method.  Do whatever you need to do to the byte[] that the client passed.  You typically need your own byte[] buffer, call Flush() if it is getting too large.  Or FileStream.Write() directly if you don't need a buffer.
- Implement the Flush method.  Call FileStream.Write() for your buffer, then its Flush().
- Implement Close and Dispose(), call the corresponding FileStream method.

Answer (score 2):

Note that XOR is going to be incredibly easy to break if the other end knows anything about the original data. If it knows the correct 8 bytes at any position, your "encryption" is immediately broken. Are you *really* sure you want to do this? Coming up with your own encryption scheme is almost *always* a bad idea - is there any reason you don't want to use one of the many encryption algorithms built into the framework? Sure, use a hardware dongle to derive the key - but then use a normal `CryptoStream`.

However, if you really want to do this, there are two obvious options:

- Build a stream wrapper, yes. Unless you really need to support the async operations, I wouldn't do so - it'll make things tougher. Write a stream implementation which takes another stream to proxy to as well as the `long` value to XOR with, and then whenever you read or write data, apply the XOR.
- Build an implementation of `ICryptoTransform`. Then you can potentially get `CryptoStream` to do all the heavy lifting in terms of the stream stuff - you just need to know how to transform a block at a time. I believe this *should* be pretty simple, but I can't say I've ever done it myself.

Comment: true... this especially apparent if the file contains large amounts of zeroes. The zeroes are transformed into your EOR key, making it very obvious what your key is if someone does a simple hexfile dump.